# What is an efficient way to create an adjacency list using STL in C++?

Tags: c++, list, graph, stl, vector

I currently use a vector of vectors like following:

```
typedef pair<int, int> vertex;
vector < vector<vertex> > adj_list(n); // n is number of vertices

// Input graph
for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++ )
{
   cin >> source >> target >> weight;
   vertex v(target, weight);
   adj_list[source].push_back(v);
}
```

Is vector of list ie.

```
vector < list<vertex> > adj_list(n);
```

a better option? If yes, why? My primary concern is creating the adjacency list efficiently, and to be able to read all the vertices connected to a particular vertex fast, for implementing Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Allocation-once would be good idea. So this is better : `vector< vector<vertex>> adj_list(n, vector<vertex>(edges));`

Comment: `vector<vector<vertex>>` is probably best but the only way to know for sure is to benchmark your application using different options.

Comment: @Nawaz: looking at the code `edges` is the **total** number of edges in the graph. You don't want each list associated to a vertex to be that big.

Comment: Dijsktra's algorithm requires a priority queue, not a list.  (I believe it is the reason Fibonacci heaps were invented...)  You can use a `std::priority_queue` to get reasonable performance, or roll your own Fibonacci heap implementation

Answer (score 2):

For that I would use std::deque<>, since you most likely don't need to remove elements from the middle (which is why someone would ever want to use std::list<>). It should be more efficient than std::vector<> or std::list<>. Having contiguous memory (vector) and removable items (list) has it's price - costly resizes for vector and pointer dereferencing/scattered memory for list.

See also: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm

Note that if you are targeting algorithmic contests, you may be surprised how much memory such STL based data structure can take.

Answer (score 2):

Your demand is fast insertion and fast iteration. Asymptotically, there is no difference between `vector<vector<T> >` and `vector<list<T> >`:

- `list<T>` is a doubly linked list, so every insert takes `O(1)` time, and iteration takes `O(1)` time per element.
- `vector<T>` is an array, implemented such that every insert takes `O(1)` (amortized) time[1], and iteration takes `O(1)` time per element.

The constants for the operations are probably different, but that's something you have to find out through profiling.

However, spatial efficiency would favour `vector<vector<T> >`, because every element in `vector<list<T> >` also carries a forward and backward pointer. So you probably want to use `vector<vector<T> >`, but in a way that you avoid the reallocations in the common case (to save time), but don't reserve too much (to save space).

For the outer vector, you can just call [`.reserve(n)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) on it, where `n` is the number of vertices in the graph.

For the inner vector, it's a bit harder, and it really depends on how your data is fed to this procedure.

---

[1] An implementation of `vector<T>` should double its capacity every time it reallocates, so the time taken by reallocation is `O(1+2+4+...+n/4+n/2+n) = O(n(1/n+2/n+4/n+...+1/4+1/2+1)) <= O(1+1/2+1/4+...)) = O(2n)`. So distributed over `n` elements, insertion takes `O(1)` (amortized) time.

Comment: `push_back` on `std::vector` is O(1), not (log n) amortized time.

Comment: `push_back` will cause reallocation when the capacity of a vector is surpassed. Reallocation takes `O(n)` time, because it has to copy the list to the newly reallocated storage. Reallocation only happens `O(log n)` times when you're inserting `n` elements, because the capacity is increased exponentially. If you amortize the total cost `O(n log n)` over every element, you'll see that `push_back` costs `O(log n)` (amortized) time per element.

Comment: Yes, reallocation happens O(log n) times, but each time is twice as large as the previous, so the total work is much smaller.  The total is O(n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1), which O(n), not O(n log n)...  Which is O(1) per element amortized.  Trust me on this; you are mistaken.  Read [any reference for std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/#complexity) (including the standard).

Comment: Ah, yes, I stand corrected: n+n/2+n/4+...+1 < n(1/1+1/2+1/4+...) = n. I'll change my answer.

Comment: I already suspected that my assumption about the cost of reallocation was wrong in some way ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create an adjacency list for graphs is to use "forward list"(considering your language in C++). For more reference, please visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/forward-list-c-set-1-introduction-important-functions/

Please read the code below for illustration of "forward list"
NOTE:- Before you read the code, understand the utility functions provided by the STL library for "forward list" properly.

```
/* The code has been designed to give output only if ENTER key is pressed, 
before that it'll keep 
recieving inputs from the user. So provide all your inputs in one line 
seperated by whitespaces. */

                      /* This is the implementation of DFS */

#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list>
using namespace std;

class graph{
    private:
        int noOfVertices;
        forward_list<int> *adj;
        void dfsUtil(int v, bool *visited);
    public:
        graph(int v);
        void addEdge(int s, int d);
        void dfs(int startVertex);
};

graph::graph(int v){
    noOfVertices = v;
    adj = new forward_list<int>[noOfVertices];
}

void graph::addEdge(int s, int d){
    adj[s].push_front(d);       
}

void graph::dfs(int startVertex){
    bool *visited = new bool[noOfVertices];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfVertices ; i++){
        visited[i] = false;
        adj[i].reverse();
    }

    dfsUtil(startVertex, visited);
}

void graph::dfsUtil(int v, bool *visited){
    forward_list<int>::iterator i; 
    visited[v] = true;
    cout << v << " ";

    for(i = adj[v].begin() ; i != adj[v].end() ; i++){
        if(!visited[*i])
            dfsUtil(*i, visited);
    } 
}

int main(){
    int v, s, d;
    cin >> v;
    graph g(v);

    while(cin.peek() != '\n')
    {
        cin >> s >> d;
        g.addEdge(s, d);
    }

    g.dfs(2);
}
```